# How to update an image link automatically on a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to update image link automatically using jquery. 
I can use the jquery code below to get the part of the link from the db: 
`/data/image_smll.png my final link to work needs to be like:<img src="../components/com/opencart/image/data/image_smll.png" alt="PC Part" width="110" height="42">`
I have tried to use span after `src="../components/com/opencart/image<span id="cimage"></span>"`
but the id is breaking the code. I am not sure I am doing the right thing here. Help.
I want to do the same thing for normal links

```
$('#name').change(function(){
var name = $('#name').val();
if ($.trim(name) !='') {
    $.post('http://site99.com/action/subs/name2.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
        $('#cimage').text(data);        
 });

   }
});
```

Comment: I am sure there is a better way to do this but I am not a reel dev guy

Comment: `$('selector_for_IMG-elment').attr('src','new_url_for_image')`  I mean you can access directly to IMG element and set SRC attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `src` attribute.

Put an id in the img tag and change

`$('#cimage').text(data);`

to

`$('#imgId').attr('src', '../components/com/opencart/image'+data);`